# Generating balls and box combinations depending on set rules

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm

I am working on a project in which I have three box (as of now) and each box will have some color of balls, so I am storing the input in a `Map` of `String` and `List` of `String` as shown below:

```
Map<String, List<String>> boxBallMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Data in the above map can be like this. Below is one possible input combination and each box won't have same color balls, so two blues is not possible in `box1` as an input:

```
{box1=[blue, red, orange]}
{box2=[blue, red, orange]}
{box3=[blue, red, orange]}
```

Basis on the above input, I need to return a mapping which will be `List<Map<String, String>>`, so for above input below mapping would be returned as an output (this is one possible output combination which follows the below rules):

```
[{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}, 
{box1=red, box2=orange, box3=blue}, 
{box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}]
```

Some rules:

1. In each row, boxes should have an alternate colors of ball. If you see above, each row has an alternate color of balls for each box - meaning `blue` for `box1`, `red` for `box2`, `orange` for `box3` in the first row.
2. I cannot have same color of balls in each row, so the below combination is not possible as it has same color of balls for two boxes in one row:

   ```
   {box1=blue, box2=blue, box3=orange}
   ```
3. In the next row, I won't use those balls for the box which have been used in the earlier rows, so the second row cannot have `blue` for `box1` as it was already used in the first row by `box1`.

Below is the code I have so far which works fine on some input combinations but somehow doesn't work on some of the input combinations:

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> generateMappings(Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    // find all boxes
    List<String> boxes = new ArrayList<String>(input.keySet());

    // find all colors
    Set<String> distinctColors = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(List<String> e : input.values()) {
        for(String color : e) {
            if(! distinctColors.contains(color)) {
                distinctColors.add(color);  
            }
        }
    }
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>(distinctColors);

    int colorIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        output.add(row);
        colorIndex = i;
        for(int j = 0; j < colors.size(); j++) {
            int boxIndex = j;
            if(boxIndex >= boxes.size()) {
                boxIndex = 0;
            }
            String box = boxes.get(boxIndex);
            List<String> boxColors = input.get(box);
            if(colorIndex >= colors.size()) {
                colorIndex = 0;
            }
            String color = colors.get(colorIndex++);
            // a combination is generated only if the actual
            // colors does exist in the actual box
            if(boxColors.contains(color)) {
                row.put(box, color);    
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Sample Unit Test

```
Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
input.put("box3", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));

List<Map<String, String>> output = create(input);
for(Map<String, String> e : output) {
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

And

```
Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
input.put("box3", Collections.<String>emptyList());

List<Map<String, String>> output = create(input);
for(Map<String, String> e : output) {
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

And

```
Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red"));
input.put("box3", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));

List<Map<String, String>> output = create(input);
for(Map<String, String> e : output) {
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

Is there any better way of solving this algorithm?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements, say on top of your sample input I have `{box4=[blue,blue]}` what would the expected output be? It would be nice if you also added some unit tests.

Comment: Sample input won't be like that.. It will always be different colors balls for same box in each row. Just updated the question..

Comment: These are not [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)... these are samples... at least give the expected output... is the requirement that the color order will always be "blue", "red", "orange"? Are more colors allowed?

Comment: There might be more colors allowed as well.. I thought those code will be sufficient.. Expected output is based on those rules I have.. let me try to grab the outputs if possible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, save some manual checking work and make your [test self-checking](http://xunitpatterns.com/Goals%20of%20Test%20Automation.html) with JUnit and Google Guava:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

...

@Test
public void test1() {
    final Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box3", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));

    final List<Map<String, String>> output = Generator.generateMappings(input);

    final List<Map<String, String>> expected = newArrayList();
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "blue", "box2", "red", "box3", "orange"));
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "red", "box2", "orange", "box3", "blue"));
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "orange", "box2", "blue", "box3", "red"));

    assertEquals(expected, output);
}

@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    final Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box3", Collections.<String> emptyList());

    final List<Map<String, String>> output = Generator.generateMappings(input);

    final List<Map<String, String>> expected = newArrayList();
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "blue", "box2", "red"));
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "red", "box2", "orange"));
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "orange", "box2", "blue"));

    assertEquals(expected, output);
}

@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {
    final Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red"));
    input.put("box3", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));

    final List<Map<String, String>> output = Generator.generateMappings(input);

    final List<Map<String, String>> expected = newArrayList();
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "blue", "box2", "red", "box3", "orange"));
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "red", "box3", "blue"));
    expected.add(ImmutableMap.of("box1", "orange", "box2", "blue", "box3", "red"));

    assertEquals(expected, output);
}
```

Then make it a little bit more readable with extracted out methods and `new*` factory methods:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import static com.google.common.collect.Maps.newLinkedHashMap;

...

public static List<Map<String, String>> generateMappings(
        Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    final List<Map<String, String>> output = newArrayList();
    final List<String> boxes = getAllBoxes(input);
    final List<String> colors = getAllColors(input);

    int colorIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
        ...
    }
    return output;
}

private static List<String> getAllBoxes(
        Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    return newArrayList(input.keySet());
}

private static List<String> getAllColors(
        Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    final Set<String> distinctColors = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (final List<String> e: input.values()) {
        for (final String color: e) {
            if (!distinctColors.contains(color)) {
                distinctColors.add(color);
            }
        }
    }
    final List<String> colors = newArrayList(distinctColors);
    return colors;
}
```

Note that it made the comments superfluous so I removed them.

I don't completely understand the requirements nor the code but maybe I'm just too tired. Anyway, I'd suggest you another approach: Generate every possible row (invalid ones too) and decide with one or more `Rule` classes whether a row is valid or not.

Pseudocode:

```
public interface Rule {
    boolean isValidRow(row, acceptedRows);
}

public class AndRule implements Rule {
    List<Rule> rules;

    public AndRule(Rule rules...) {
        this.rules = newArrayList(rules);
    }

    public boolean isValidRow(row, acceptedRows) {
        for (Rule rule: rules) {
            if (!rule.isValidRow(row, acceptedRows)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Rule mainRule = new AndRule(rule1, rule2, rule3);

List<Map<String, String>> output = newArrayList();
// maybe you need nested loops here, but an Iterator would be better
for (...) { 
    Map<String, String> row = createNextRow(...);
    if (mainRule.isValidRow(row, output)) {
        output.add(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I was able to find a solution for this from your suggestion.. Appreciated your help.. I also have similar question [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42982/find-an-element-from-multiple-sorted-lists-efficiently). Can you take a look if possible?