# Finding an element in multiple sorted lists efficiently

Tags: java, optimization, performance, algorithm, search

I have \$k\$ sorted `List`s, each of size \$n\$. Currently I have hard-coded 5 sorted `List`s each of size 3, but in general that is configurable.

I would like to search for single element in each of the \$k\$ `List`s (or its predecessor, if it doesn't exist).

Obviously I can binary search each List individually, resulting in a \$O(k*log(n))\$ runtime. But I think we can do better than that: after all, we're doing the same search \$k\$ times.

Could this be improved?

```
private static TreeSet<Integer> tree = new TreeSet<Integer>();

public SearchItem(final List<List<Integer>> inputs) {
    tree = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (List<Integer> input : inputs) {
        tree.addAll(input);
    }
}

public Integer getItem(final Integer x) {
    if(tree.contains(x)) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return tree.higher(x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 6));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 6));
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 8, 13));

    lists.add(list1);
    lists.add(list2);
    lists.add(list3);
    lists.add(list4);
    lists.add(list5);

    SearchItem search = new SearchItem(lists);
    System.out.println(tree);

    Integer dataOuput = search.getItem(5);

    System.out.println(dataOuput);
}
```

Comment: Question: In your text you say: *I would like to search for single element in each of the k Lists (or its predecessor, if it doesn't exist).* but in your code you get the `*successor* not the *predecessor*. Which one is right?

Comment: @rolfl: I just updated the question.. I miss couple of important points.. I have rewrote most of the things.. Now take a look.. It will make sense now.. I guess now you will be angry as in the question lot of things might have change as corresponding to what you have suggested :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have some misguided assumptions here.

For a start, what you have now is not \$O(k \log(n))\$, it first scans and sorts all the data in to the tree, which is a \$O(N \log(N))\$ operation, where \$N\$ is the cumulative data size (sum of input-array sizes). Then, the check on it, is a \$O(\log(N))\$ check, so, your algorithm is in the order of \$O(N\log(N))\$.

The complexity you are worried about \$O(k\log(n))\$ is really quite trivial. \$k\$ is a small number (5), and `log(n)` is always small... in many ways, after n = 128 it is effectively a constant....

So, I would do the following:

1. binary search each List
2. keep the 'min' value

with the code:

```
Integer result = null;
for (List<Integer> data : lists) {
    int pos = Collections.binarySearch(data, input);
    if (pos >= 0) {
        //exact match, return
        return data.get(pos);
    }
    pos = -pos - 1;
    if (pos < data.size()) {
        Integer found = data.get(pos);
        if (result == null || result.compareTo(found) > 0) {
            result = found;
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

Now, if you wanted to be fancy, and you wanted the fastest response times, you could put each binary search in to a `Callable<Integer>`, and run them in parallel....

Then rank the results, and teturn it all in time complexity \$O(\log(n))\$ assuming \$k\$ is less than your hardware CPU count.

Answer (score 5):

Two quick notes about the code in the question:

1. A bug: a client could create more than one instance of the class but all of them will use the same `TreeSet` instance since it's static.
2. ```
   public Integer getItem(final Integer x) {
       if(tree.contains(x)) {
           return x;
       } else {
           return tree.higher(x);
       }
   }
   ```

   The following is the same:

   ```
   public Integer getItem(final Integer x) {
       return tree.ceiling(x);
   }
   ```